# Typescript: Use SET of interface property used by a class when only one property is changed?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface (which resembles the database structure) as such:

```
export interface Body {
    health: number;
    height: number;
    hairlength: number;
}
```

and a class as following

```
export class Person {
    private _body: Body;
    private _name: string;
    private _age: number;
    constructor()....


    get body(): Body {
        return this._body
    }
}
```

is there a way to use get/set on the body interface inside the class when only one property is changed from outside the class, e.g.:

```
    set body.hairlength(n: number) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
```

so a *haircutter* could use:

```
static performHairCut(p: Person) {
    p.body.hairlength -= 10
}
```

With this idea I want to seperate repeatedly updating properties from "occasional" ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `Body` object directly you can return object containing getters/setters like:

```
export interface Body {
    health: number;
    height: number;
    hairlength: number;
}

export class Person {
    private _body!: Body;

    constructor() { }


    get body(): Body {
        const that = this;

        return {
            get health() {
                return that._body.health;
            },
            set health(newValue: number) {
                that.body.health = newValue
            },
            get height() {
                return that._body.height;
            },
            set height(newValue: number) {
                that.body.height = newValue
            },
            get hairlength() {
                return that._body.hairlength;
            },
            set hairlength(newValue: number) {
                that.body.hairlength = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't recommend this approach. In my opinion code like this is obscure and can get messy very quickly with bigger interfaces (especially if they contain nested structures). You should check out [ES6 proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: You can "NEST" get/setter ? I didn't even think about this! I will try it and report :)

Comment: Now i know what you mean with "messy quickly". I accept your answer but I will stick to a proper implementation. Kudos!